# What do Ruby Feature/Bug numbers correspond to?

Tags: ruby

I notice in the Ruby NEWS announcements that there are references to Feature and Bug numbers.

For example, in the doc below, there are references to [Feature #4276] and [Bug #9593]. What do these numbers correspond to (Github IDs, IDs on some other service, etc.) and how can I read more about the corresponding features and bugs using those ids?

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS-2.2.0

Comment: They're issue/ticket ids in ruby's redmine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergio Tulentsev described, the numbers correspond to bugs and features within the Ruby tracking system at this website:

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk

Given an id for a bug, the discussion of the bug can be found using this URL pattern:

`https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/:bug_id`

And the same for features:

`https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/:feature_id`